# Python regex - stripping out HTML tags and formatting characters from inner HTML

Tags: python

I'm dealing with single HTML strings like this

```
>> s = 'u><br/>\n                                    Some text <br/><br/><u'
```

where I've got meaningful text embedded inside broken HTML or incomplete HTML tags. I need to extract only that inner text, and ignore the broken HTML. How can I do this? I'm using

```
>> re.search(r'(.>)(<.>)(.>)', s)
>>
```

but this returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you're looking to take this input:

```
u><br/>\n                                    Some text <br/><br/><u
```

And receive this output:

```
\n                                    Some text
```

This is done simply enough by only caring about what comes between the two inward-pointing brackets. We want:

- A right-bracket `>` (so we know where to begin)
- Some text `\n                                    Some text` (the content) which does not contain a left-bracket
- A left-bracket `<` (so we know where to end)

You want:

```
>>> s = 'u><br/>\n                                    Some text <br/><br/><u'
>>> re.search(r'>([^<]+)<', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 55), match='>\n                                    Some text >
```

(The captured group can be accessed via `.group(1)`.)

Additionally, you may want to use `re.findall` if you expect there to be multiple matches per line:

```
>>> re.findall(r'>([^<]+)<', s)
['\n                                    Some text ']
```

EDIT: To address the comment: If you have multiple matches and you want to connect them into a single string (effectively removing all HTML-like tag things), do:

```
>>> s = 'nbsp;<br><br>Some text.<br>Some \n more text.<br'
>>> ' '.join(re.findall(r'>([^<]+)<', s))
'Some text. Some \n more text.'
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if `s` is something like `nbsp;<br><br>Some text.<br>Some \n                                   more text.<br`, and I need to strip out all the HTML and formatting to just get `Some text. Some \n                                   more text.`?