# How to retrieve the details inside < td >< /td > using regex

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to extract details from Cvedetails.com using some loop and regex and i need help with extracting the table data using regex [image: Regex table]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex - stripping out HTML tags and formatting characters from inner HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064469/python-regex-stripping-out-html-tags-and-formatting-characters-from-inner-html)

Comment: Regular expressions are not the way to deal with markup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing HTML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-using-python)

Comment: Please share your coding attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually regex isn't the best way to go when dealing with HTML (or any other markup, for that matter).

Try taking a look in [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) package for python